Nifi, avro schema for Xml file Exception
I'm trying to use the following schema for reading xml file with XMLReader service:
     {
       "name": "test",
       "namespace": "nifi",
       "type": "record",
       "fields": [
          {
           "name": "root",
           "type": {
           "name": "RecordForTag",
           "type": "record",
           "fields": [
               {
                "name": "nested1",
                "type": {
                "name": "RecordForTag",
                "type": "record",
                       "fields": [
                          {
                         "name": "nested1",
                         "type": "string"
                          }
                        ]
               }
              }
            ]
           }
          }
        ]
       }

according to examples in https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.7.0/org.apache.nifi.xml.XMLReader/additionalDetails.html
But got the error:
 Not a valid Avro Schema Cant redefine nifi.RecordForTag

What am I doing wrong?

Follow these specification while creating AVRO schema - https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/
Also, there are several online schema validator tools, so use those to validate your schema before putting into NiFi.
